# In the bitbucket cloud UI how do I filter out the branches that have that had the PR rejected

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-cloud

Bitbucket cloud allows you to filter the active, merged or all branches. If I have to check the branches that don't have PRs raised I will need to click each one individually as it might have a PR declined. Is there a way to filter those branches that have PRs declined or a way to view them anyway.
The only solution I am thinking is getting the information through API and processing it in a script.